# Create a symbol-like shape in tikz and reuse it easily?

Tags: tikz-pgf, symbols, tikz-arrows

I wanted to create something like a circle and place arrows around it facing towards the circle (or maybe rectangle):

[image]

I did it in this way, if someone has improvements since my approach is very manually, you are welcome:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\def\size{2}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[circle, draw, text width=\size cm, text height=\size cm](down){};
\foreach \x/\y in {
north/90,
north east/45, 
east/0, 
south east/315,
south/270,
south west/225, 
west/180,
 north west/135}
{\draw[latex-] (down.\x) to ++ (\y:1cm);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I now want to use this picture inside a bigger tikz_diagramm like a easy, maybe scalable, symbol. Is there a more efficient way than create a new tikz-environment inside node (where the symbol is needed) and copy&paste the code above?

Do you maybe know good repsoitories for already predefines symbols in tikz (something like [tikssymbols](https://ctan.org/pkg/tikzsymbols?lang=de))?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `pic`s for such things. They can have parameters, here it is the size. Notice also that `north` and `90` are equivalent, so you only need one variable in the loop.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\tikzset{pics/.cd,
            funky circle/.style={
            code={
            \node[circle, draw,minimum size=#1](down){};
            \foreach \X in {90,45,...,-225}
            {\draw[latex-] (down.\X) to ++ (\X:1cm);}
            }}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path (0,0) pic{funky circle=2cm};
\path (4,2) pic{funky circle=1cm};
\path (pi,-1) pic[blue]{funky circle=1cm};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Just for fun: you can use these things for funky tasks.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\tikzset{pics/.cd,
            funky circle/.style={
            code={
            \node[circle, draw,minimum size=#1](-down){};
            \foreach \X in {0,45,...,315}
            {\draw[latex-] (-down.\X) to ++ (\X:1cm) coordinate(-\X);}
            }}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pic (Emma) at (0,0) {funky circle=2cm};
\pic (Elisa) at (4,2) {funky circle=1cm};
\path (pi,-1) pic[blue,rotate=30,transform shape]{funky circle=1cm};
\draw[red,latex-latex] (Elisa-135) to[out=135,in=90] (Emma-90);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you see, some care has to be taken when rotating these pics: since you have a node inside, you have to add `transform shape`. This is particularly subtle here because a rotated circle does have the same shape as the unrotated one. Transform shape does, however, transform the anchors `90` and so on that are used in the construction of the `pic`.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you. Is there some kind of way like for the figure-environment to say 'place the picture HERE where the code is'? Background: I am inside a textnode and write someting, then the mentiones symbol should appear after the word and then the text continues. My current code looks like this: \node[rectangle] (kp){this is text before picture \tikz \path (0,0) pic{funky circle=.3cm}; this is text after picture}; Currently the (0,0) coordinate positions the symbol not in the best places and I manually try to figure out what value perfects best. Maybe there is a automatic function?

Comment: @SRel I guess you do not need any of this. You could just do `bla bla bla \tikz[baseline=(Emma-down.south)]{\pic (Emma){funky circle=6mm};}
bla bla bla`. If you choose another `base`, e.g. `(Emma-down.center)`, you move the funky circle down.